# Is it possible to format the value of date time picker in my code?

Tags: vb.net

The code below is to display the order history for my module. I code it for the data grid view to display data/record according to the date selected by the user in the date time picker. It works fine but I wanted to format the date time to show in ddMMMyyyy format, is there any way I can achieve that?

```
  strSQL = "Select INBKG_STSFG, Case INBKG_STSFG When 3 Then 'Complete' END AS STSFG, "
  strSQL &= "INBKG_BKGID, INBKG_BKGDT, CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), INBKG_BKGDT, 103), INBKG_USRID, "
  strSQL &= "INBKG_MATCD, INBKG_BKGQT, INBKG_RECID "
  strSQL &= "FROM INBKG_TBL "
  strSQL &= "WHERE INBKG_STSFG In ('3')"
  strSQL &= "AND INBKG_BKGDT >= '" & gfSQLDate(dtBKGDT1.Value) & "'"
  strSQL &= "ORDER BY INBKG_BKGDT, INBKG_RECID"
  dt = ExecProc(strSQL)
```

Comment: Where you want to format that, in GridView or in DateTimePicker.

Comment: @HirenPatel I want it to show in Data Grid View

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert the DateTimePicker value as below.

```
dtBKGDT1.Value.ToString("dd/MMM/yyyy")
```

Comment: Oops, I'm sorry! I actually wanted it to change in date time picker instead of data grid view. I'm not thinking straight just now.

Comment: @StillGotAlotToLearn , I've updated the answer please check.

Comment: I see, It's more simple than I thought!

Comment: Please feel free to upvote the answer.